# What's wrong with this append?

Tags: scheme, racket

Racket is giving me a contract violation for the following code:

```
(define (fringe x)
  (append (car x) (fringe (cdr x))))
```

Any ideas what's wrong with it?

Comment: Without context, you're depending on hoping people know what the function `fringe` is supposed to do.  Don't make us guess: tell us what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because `(car x)` is *not* returning a list (it's hard to tell for sure without knowing the actual value of `x` that's rising the error). `append` is an operation defined between two lists. If you want to add an *element* at the head of a list, use `cons` instead of `append`.

This is what I mean:

```
(append 1 '(2 3))
=> append: expected argument of type <proper list>; given 1

(append '(1) '(2 3))
=> '(1 2 3)

(cons 1 '(2 3)) ; the recommended way!
=> '(1 2 3)
```